# Row inside a Column with Expanded (AutosizeText not resizing)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a [AutosizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) widget wrapped in a column and a row. It doesn't resize, it overflows and when I wrap the AutosizeText into an expanded widget it (as suggested by the AutosizeText package) there's an Error: `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#2f4c1 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`

Here is a minimal reproducible sample:

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  const Example({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: const [
                AutoSizeText('subject',
                    maxLines: 1,
                    minFontSize: 16,
                    overflowReplacement: Text(
                      'subject',
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the widgetTree of the App.

[image: Here is the Widget Tree of the App]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is because of the first `Row` Widget as they said:

> When a `row` is in a parent that does not provide a finite width constraint `it will try to shrink-wrap its children along` the horizontal axis

so here the `Row` Widget is trying to shrink its child `AutoSizeText` and here will be a second problem that if the text is bigger than the screen size it will overflow.

- the solution here is to expand the `AutoSizeText`, but here will be another problem, as they said:

> Setting a flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that `the child is to expand to fill the remaining space` in the horizontal direction

> These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent

as you can see the `Row` Widget is trying to shrink its child, at the same time the `Expanded` Widget is trying to expand it, so they will conflict with each other and that causes your problem.

- The safe solution here is to wrap 'AutoSizeText' with Expanded and as my dear friend `#Dulaj Nadawa` said: is to wrap The `Column` Widget with `Expanded` too

### and for sure avoid using unnecessary Widgets

[image].

hope I could help.

Comment: Now the resizing works, but I'm still getting: Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Comment: can you write more info?

Comment: Sure thing, what Info would you need?

Comment: The whole widget tree to know exactly what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping both `Column` and `AutosizeText` with `Expanded`

Comment: Still the same exception:
NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

Comment: Which widget is the parent of the first Row?

Comment: Updated the answer please check

Comment: I wrapped both inside Expanded, still same error :/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                          'The text to display sdasdasdadsd das dasd as da das da s as dasd ad as da s dads asdas das dsd s',
                          maxLines: 1,
                          minFontSize: 16,
                          overflowReplacement: Text(
                            'subject',
                          )),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.purple,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hmmm, still getting the same exception: 
NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

Comment: now it is related to your parent widget, please add your full code. Generally this issue come from there you have unlimited size child in your widget tree, like expanded(child:AutoSizeText), in this case one of the things you should attention to is if you have row or column you should make sure set needed layout by expanding of their children like what I do in my answer. follow this guild and you will find the issue.